# bubble sort a string array by length of string

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, bubble-sort

I am wondering how to use Bubble Sorting to sort a list of names ( like: Bob, Robert, Dave, Kelly) in increasing order of the length of their names. I know how to use bubble sort to sort their names alphabetically, but just want to know how to sort by their name length. Would I have to convert to names to integers and then sort the integers by amount?
Thanks,

Comment: instead of comparing which comes first in alphabet just compare their `.length()`

Comment: Instead of `name1.compareTo(name2)` use `Integer.compare(name1.length(), name2.length())`.

Comment: How would I use a Bucket Sort to do the exact same thing?

Answer (score 0):

When comparing two `String` values by length instead of alphabetically, use the `String.length()` method instead of using `String.compareTo()`

ie: change your

```
if(a.compareTo(b) < 0)
```

to

```
if(a.length() < b.length())
```

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error?  Try using `String.length()` instead of `String.length`

Comment: thank you very much the () worked, I was wondering why it would not compile.

Comment: This is because `String` has a `.length()` method, not a `.length` field: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Edit your question with your current code, do you have something reading the file already?